# strange while statement behaviour?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot figure out why the following statements dont work.

```
randomKey = random.choice(list(topic.keys()))
randomValue = random.choice(topic[randomKey])

current = "-" * len(randomValue) 
while current != randomValue: 
   (statements)
else:
   (statements)
```

However, if i alter the 1st line to

```
while current == randomValue:
```

the statement after 'else' executes correctly. Otherwise, the statement after 'else' does not execute. Any idea why what may be causing the strange behaviour? Full code has been excluded for it will run through this entire page.

Comment: There's no way we can do better than just wild guessing if you don't boil this down to a simple working example.  Either the while condition is never true, or you have a `break` in there somewhere...

Comment: thank you, but i looked thru the entire code & there was no break keyword :(

Comment: do kindly view my edit. Was wondering if 'random' causes that strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the Python grammar.  From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

> This [a `while` statement] repeatedly tests the expression and, if it is true, executes the first suite; if the expression is false (which may be the first time it is tested) the suite of the `else` clause, if present, is executed and the loop terminates.

So in the first case, it must be that the while condition never evaluates to false, while in the second it eventually does.  Note that explicitly breaking out of the loop will *not* execute the else clause.

Comment: thank you, but i looked thru the entire code & there was no break keyword :(

Comment: do kindly view my edit. Was wondering if 'random' causes that strange behaviour ?

Comment: @brainsfrying: The answer is still the same.  It is possible that your random choices are causing the condition to evaluate false in one situation and not in the other.  Instead of using random, can you provide a deterministic example with a fixed value that always fails/succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

`else`, when used with `while`, runs after the while expression evaluates to a falsy value if the while loop finishes by the expression being false, instead of being broken out of by a `break` statement (or execution leaving the function via a `return` or `raise`-ing an exception). Your while condition in your second example must fail, so there's no opportunity for a `break` to occur, the function to return or an exception to be thrown, so the `else` statements will always run.

[docs for while](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)

Comment: thank you, but i looked thru the entire code & there was no break keyword :(

Comment: do kindly view my edit. Was wondering if 'random' causes that strange behaviour ?