# strange while behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange while statement behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212173/strange-while-statement-behaviour)

Given the following, how may I implement list comprehension correctly, exit the loop & run the statements after 'else'? I had tried to scan for '-' characters but it does not work.

Have tried:

```
while(current != randomValue)
```

Trying now:

```
randomKey = random.choice(list(topic.keys()))

randomValue = random.choice(topic[randomKey])

current = "-" * len(randomValue)  

while (i for i in range (0, len(current)) if i != "-"):
    (statements)
else:
    (statements)
```

Comment: hi :) i tried a workaround since i need my prev post to work so badly. Same issue & person by the way :) Sorry.

Comment: anw many thanks i tried something else & it worked. A simple solution after so long. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test doesn't make sense -- Bool on a generator is always `True`:

```
>>> a = (i for i in range(10))
>>> bool(a)
True
```

Also `i` will never == '`-'` since you're looping over `range`.  I'm not really sure what you're trying here, but we really can't help you solve this unless we see you can manage to boil your actual code down to the minimum important portion.  (And who knows, by doing that, you might find the problem yourself)

Comment: anw many thanks i tried something else & it worked. A simple solution after so long. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list comprehension, struggling to make the while statement false etc... I did this, which worked in a way:

```
while ("-" in current ):
```